# Tailwind classes not working in vite project

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, vite

I am following the official tailwind documentation on how to install tailwind in vite projects using vue. I followed the tutorial step by step and my tailwind classes dont seem to be working. I am not sure what the issue is so I was hoping I can get some help.

here is what my tailwind config file looks like:

[image]

[image: and here us what my frontend directory structure looks like]

and here us what my frontend directory structure looks like

Comment: did you add the tailwind style to the style.css and import it in main.ts?

Comment: I added them to the style.css but I didnt import them in main.ts. How do i do that

Comment: `import './style.css'` in the top of main.ts